# How do I apply a patch against a .php file in MediaWiki?

Tags: php, mediawiki, patch, adsense

I'm trying to integrate Google Adsense into my MediaWiki site with the ShoutWikiAds (http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ShoutWiki_Ads) extension.

Step 2 reads: *Apply the patch against your $IP/skins/MonoBook.php.*

The patch is:

```
Index: MonoBook.php
===================================================================
--- MonoBook.php    (revision 88394)
+++ MonoBook.php    (working copy)
@@ -98,7 +98,9 @@
        <?php if($this->data['dataAfterContent']) { $this->html ('dataAfterContent'); } ?>
        <div class="visualClear"></div>
    </div>
-</div></div>
+</div>
+<?php /* ShoutWiki patch */ wfRunHooks( 'MonoBookAfterContent' ); ?>
+</div>
 <div id="column-one"<?php $this->html('userlangattributes')  ?>>
 <?php $this->cactions( $skin ); ?>
    <div class="portlet" id="p-personal">
@@ -257,6 +259,7 @@
        </div>
    </div>
 <?php
+   /* ShoutWiki patch */wfRunHooks( 'MonoBookAfterToolbox' );
    }

    /*************************************************************************************************/
```

How do I apply this patch against the monobook.php file? Do I just copy/paste it in the monobook.php file?

A very clear and easy to understand answer would be very much appreciated!

Comment: This is a bad idea. Every time you (or your web host) upgrade your wiki, your patch will be gone. Also, this will only work for users who have the MonoBook skin, which is not even the default skin any longer (Vector is).

Answer (score 1):

place the file.patch into the same directory of the file and use the following command

```
patch < file.patch
```

change the "file.patch" to the correct filename accordingly.

Comment: Ok, so I create a new file named file.patch (or whatever.patch) and copy/paste the patch code in it and then I place it in the same directory as the directory as the monobook.php file.

The next step is unknown ground to me...

What do you mean by "use the following command"? Where/how do I use this command to patch the monobook.php file?

Comment: Would you be kind enough to post a simple step-by-step on how I can patch this file? I'm fairly new to this... (I've searched google to find anything that can help me understand your instuctions but I'm afraid I didn't find anything that can make this clear to me)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you familiar with ssh or linux it self? Are you working with linux? I ask because if you don't know what I mean with shell / bash it seems to me that you have no idea what I am talking about. If so, I have no idea how I can help you out.